# Invalid JSON Primitive - Custom Serialization/Deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, deserialization

I have a JSON file which is returned from web service..

```
facilityName: Ragley DRI01{
  "DataCenterManager": {
    "first": "",
    "second": "Cory Kemp"
  },
  "RegionalDataCenterManager": {
    "first": "",
    "second": "John Farrell"
  },
  "LastUpdatedBy": {
    "first": "DCInfoSyncRole",
    "second": "v-asalam"
  },
  "Client": {
    "first": "DCInfoSyncRole",
    "second": "FacilityMasterPortal"
  }
}
facilityName: Quitman, MEI01{
  "DataCenterManager": {
    "first": "",
    "second": "Cory Kemp"
  },
  "RegionalDataCenterManager": {
    "first": "",
    "second": "John Farrell"
  },
  "LastUpdatedBy": {
    "first": "DCInfoSyncRole",
    "second": "v-asalam"
  },
  "Client": {
    "first": "DCInfoSyncRole",
    "second": "FacilityMasterPortal"
  }
}
```

I know it is invalid as per [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/), But I have to deserialize this JSON Object to structured DataTable.

Do I need custom serialization/deserialization ?

Any help without using JSON.net is most appreciated..

Comment: If the Json is invalid, then it's not Json, it's a string. You will thus need to parse it yourself.

Comment: It really irks me that someone clearly went to the trouble of trying to return JSON and then gave up at the last hurdle.

Comment: JSONLint even says that mess is invalid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that the horrid format you are facing is far enough from real JSON for JSON parsers to be tweaked to parse it. The best you can do is to transform it into a valid JSON manually and then proceed to parse as you would do normally.

Of course this would be error-prone and fragile, but if you really need to do it, it is possible. Something like this would do as a start

```
 var resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
 resultBuilder.Append("[");

 var facilityNameRegex = new Regex("facilityName: ((.)+(?={))");
 var facilities = facilityNameRegex.Matches(text);
 var lastIndex = facilities.Count - 1;

 for (int i = 0; i <= lastIndex; i++)
 {
     var facilityName = facilities[i].Groups[1].Value;

     var bodyStartIndex = facilities[i].Index + facilities[i].Length;

     var body = (i < lastIndex) ?
         text.Substring(bodyStartIndex, facilities[i + 1].Index - bodyStartIndex)
         : text.Substring(bodyStartIndex);

     resultBuilder.AppendFormat("{{\"facilityName\": {0}, \"settings\": {1}}}",
         HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(facilityName, addDoubleQuotes: true),
         body);

     if (i != lastIndex)
     {
         resultBuilder.Append(",");
     }
 }

 resultBuilder.Append("]");

 Console.WriteLine(resultBuilder.ToString()); // result is a valid JSON array
```